# word2vec, how to classify text with SVM?

Tags: text, classification, svm, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a csv file, it has 2 columns: class and text_data. I first extract biGram and TriGrams, then tried to use SVM on my data for classification. But it shows "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found". I have used Gensim=4.0.0. Your help highly appreciated. Code:

```py
# all packages imported
df_covid = pd.read_csv('allCurated853_4.csv', encoding="utf8")
df_covid['label'] = df_covid['class'].map({
    'covidshutdown': 0,
    'manufactoring':1,
    'corporate':2,
    'environmental':3,
    'infrastructure':4,
    'other':5
})
X = df_covid['text_data']
y = df_covid['label']
corpus=X
lst_corpus = []
for string in corpus:
lst_words = string.split()
lst_grams = [" ".join(lst_words[i:i+1])
            for i in range(0, len(lst_words), 1)]
lst_corpus.append(lst_grams)

bigrams_detector = gensim.models.phrases.Phrases(lst_corpus,
            delimiter=" ".encode(), min_count=5, threshold=10)
bigrams_detector = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigrams_detector)
trigrams_detector = gensim.models.phrases.Phrases(bigrams_detector[lst_corpus],
            delimiter=" ".encode(), min_count=5, threshold=10)
trigrams_detector = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(trigrams_detector)

cv = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(lst_corpus, size=300, window=8,
            min_count=1, sg=1, iter=30)

X_trainCv, X_testCv, y_trainCv, y_testCv = train_test_split(cv, y, 
            test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_trainCv,y_trainCv)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_testCv)
print(classification_report(X_testCv, y_pred))
```

Complete Error message:
[image]

This is a dataset  [click here to download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdyzatj6dogzioy/allCurated853_4.csv?dl=0)

if, I do not use biGrams and triGrams and change word2Vec model to this

> cv= gensim.models.Word2Vec(lst_corpus, vector_size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)

New error message appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:\Dropbox\AAA\50-2\word2Vec_trails\word2Vec_triGrams_34445.py", line 65, in <module>
X_trainCv, X_testCv, y_trainCv, y_testCv = train_test_split(cv, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

File "C:\Users\makta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2172, in train_test_split
arrays = indexable(*arrays)

File "C:\Users\makta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 299, in indexable
check_consistent_length(*result)

File "C:\Users\makta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 259, in check_consistent_length
lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]

File "C:\Users\makta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 259, in <listcomp>
lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]

  File "C:\Users\makta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 202, in _num_samples
raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"

TypeError: Singleton array array(<gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec object at 0x000001A41DF59820>,
  dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

I made this attempt (below code) to use word2vec  vectors like count vectorizer or TFIDF. It generates output,but not corrent one. I think I should make list of lists of vectors. Help appreciated. this is Code:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_covid = pd.read_csv('allCurated853_4.csv', encoding="utf8")
df['label'] = df['class'].map({'covidshutdowncsv': 0,  'manufactoringcsv':1, 'corporatecsv':2, 'environmentalcsv':3,'infrastructurecsv':4, 'other':5})
X = df['message']
y = df['label']
X=X.to_string ()
ls = []
rows = X.splitlines(True)
print('size of rows:', len(rows))   # size of rows: 852
for i in rows:
    ls.append(i.split(' '))
print('total words:', len(ls))    # total words: 852
model = Word2Vec(ls, min_count=1, size = 4)
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
print('words in vocabolary :',len(words)) # words in vocabolary:3110
print(words)
words=words[0:852]    # problem
vectors = []
for word in words:
    vectors.append(model[word].tolist())
data = np.array(vectors)    
print('vectors of words:', len(data))   # vectors of words: 852     
X_trainCv, X_testCv, y_trainCv, y_testCv = train_test_split(data, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
clf_covid = svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_trainCv,y_trainCv)
clf_covid.score(X_testCv,y_testCv)
# score: 0.50299
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message to your question, including the traceback showing involved lines-of-code?

Comment: For the future, quoted text is better than a screenshot. But, two things: (1) your `bigram_detector` then `trigram_detector` code doesn't actually feed into later steps. Is it really important? Are you sure you want to be trying advanced `Phrases` combinations before having something more simple working? (2) Is your code modeled after something elsewhere? The choice to set `delimiter=" ".encode()` may be a little off, *and* the error seems to highlight a problem with the set `delimiter`. Why do you need a non-default delimiter, anyway?

Comment: thank you for the advice.  (1) I agree with you. advanced phrases combinations can wait before simple version work. (2) do you think the problem is in data? yes words separated via a space.

Comment: If you're putting aside phrase-combos for now, which is a good idea, there's no info in the question about any current error you're hitting - only the error from the phrasing code. So hard to have any theories! What's the blocking error once the phrasing steps are skipped?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your `cv` variable is an instance of the `Word2Vec` model, with all sorts of internal state, including among other things a collection of word-vectors that can be looked up by word keys. You are passing that `cv` instance into `scikit-learn`'s `train_test_split()` function. It's not expecting a `Word2Vec` object, but some ordered collection of input rows, one per item that's to be classified.

Comment: thank you, could you show me a solution for that!

Comment: Well, what do you want to classify, and how did you expect a `Word2Vec` model to help?

Comment: I want to classify a dataset. my dataset is there to download gojomo.

Comment: If you want someone to download your data, interpret vague requirements, and write code for you, you may be in the market for a consultant. But if you have well-formed questions about specific blocks you've hit in your own code-writing efforts, you could provide the key summary details here and maybe get more help.

Comment: I succeeded partially to use word2vec with train_test-split. let me extend my question above. Basically, there are 5 classes and some 850 texts, each row is one text, and every text has a label. I want to use 80% of the text to train the SVM model and test the model on the remaining 20 %.

Comment: How were you hoping to turn a `Word2Vec` model, with its vectors for a vocabulary of 3,110 words, into vectors for 852 multi-word texts instead? (Separately: a corpus with a mere 3k unique words is unlikely to train a very good word2vec model – as the algorithm requires large, varid training sets to work well. And, `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea with word2vec - it needs multiple contrasting examples of a word to place it well, so much so that discarding rare words, as the default `min_count=5` does, usually gives better results than keeping them.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235348/discussion-between-tursunwali-and-gojomo).

Comment: Unfortunately, chat seems to hide anything discussed from future searchers, so I prefer not to create non-reusable content like that.

Comment: agree, the chat was StackOverflow's recommendation.